# Pygame player can jump for as long as it wants

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a jumping method for my player in pygame. It goes up but I can just hold the space bar key down and it will go up for as long as I want and I don't know how to prevent it. Here's the code for my player class:

```py
import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 64))
        self.image.fill('blue')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.speed = 8
        self.jump_speed = -16
        self.gravity = 0.8

    def get_input(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d]:
            self.direction.x = 1

        elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] or keys[pygame.K_a]:
            self.direction.x = -1
        else:
            self.direction.x = 0
        
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or keys[pygame.K_w] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.jump()
    
    def apply_gravity(self):
        self.direction.y += self.gravity
        self.rect.y += self.direction.y
    
    def jump(self):
        self.direction.y = self.jump_speed

    def update(self):
        self.get_input()
```

Comment: You want to search for the Pygame KeyDown event.  This allows you to trigger jumping on key press.  you'll still need to find some way to not let them spam it but 'If y ==0' should do the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jump` event changes the way the player is moving. When a key is released, then that speed is not reverted. Use the pygame keydown event, and then the keyup event.

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

#Your code

while True:
  #Your event loop code
  for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == K_SPACE:
           player.jump()
      if event.type == KEYUP:
         if event.key == K_SPACE:
           player.revert_jump()
      if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
```